# Change UWP menu button icon image in title bar (simple way)

Tags: windows-10, uwp, titlebar, hamburger-menu

I want a hamburger menu button in my UWP app title bar.

I already know how to make a "back" button visible in the title bar and how to handle its clicked event.
I have seen samples of how to customize the title bars colors and stuff, and I have also seen some samples of how to put controls in it, but its all too much complicated.

Comment: You cannot do this the simple way. You have to customize the title bar. That's all you can do.

Comment: then can you please refer me to a proper link? I have tried a couple but they give strange errors

Comment: The official documentation is well maintaned and should give you the wanted result. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx

Comment: Hamburger menu code available on GitHub [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InVsajohErQ)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hamburger menu which is really simple but functional. No code-behind, just XAML.

https://github.com/vborovikov/hamburger

The hamburger button sits below the title bar like in any other Windows 10 apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple hamburger control, [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-021-Implementing-a-Simple-Hamburger-Navigation-Menu) is a video tutorial I followed to while learning. It is simple and does the work pretty well. The source is available on the provided link. Please mark as answer if it helped you.